# flask-migrate alembic.util.exc.CommandError python

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I am using flask-migrate to update the changes in my database. I ran  this command. and then this command

```
$python manage.py db init
$python manage.py db migrate
```

I get the error below

```
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by 'e462fd034cc1'
```

I looked on stackoverflow for similar problems where it was suggested to deleted the migrations folder which i did but still same error is coming again and again.
What should i do.

Comment: See this answer instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32356600/3865670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is out of sync with your migrations repository. For some reason the latest migration id stored in the database is not the migration id of a migration in your repository. This means that you probably deleted or modified the migration repository by hand and made it inconsistent with the current state of your database.

If this is a scratch database, maybe deleting and running the migrations again will fix the problem and give you a valid database.

Answer (score 0):

Just see what is your last migration number.
Open *migrations/versions* folder in any file manager and sort by date.
For me, for example, it ***e222b725dce9_.py***
Then change the value in ***version_num*** column in ***alembic_version*** table

*Note that I delete underscrore in the end*

### [image: My phpMyAdmin]

Then run ***python manage.py db migrate*** and ***python manage.py db upgrade*** 
All must pass successfully