# Reset Alembic after deleting migration folder

Tags: python, flask, alembic

I accidentally deleted my migrations folder. So I ran `flask db init`, and everything ran smoothly. But when I ran `flask db migrate`, it gave me this error:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
ERROR [root] Error: Can't locate revision identified by '470572fac7a1'
```

From what I understand, it's looking for my other migration folder which is long gone. How can I solve this?

Comment: Restore the deleted folder would be a good first step.

Comment: You _are_ using some kind of version control, right?

Comment: Here's the thing... I wasn't using any version control.

Comment: If you are OK losing your old migrations, just remove alembic and re-initialize it. Oh and also backup everything before you start, though I think that lesson has already been learned.

Answer (score 15):

Delete that particular record in the table alembic_version that's in your database. There's only one varchar column called version_num, so this expression should work:

`delete from alembic_version where version_num='470572fac7a1';`

Answer (score 10):

Delete the `/migrations` directory and rename/replicate your applications database. Then start from scratch.

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

Now repopulate your new empty database with data from your backup.

Comment: After deleting the `/migrations` folder, make sure the new `/migrations` folder contains the following files: alembic.ini, env.py, and script.py.mako.

Comment: this worked well for me. It generated an entirely new summary migration file. Now I have just have to deal with the different database name. I suppose I could drop the previous database and follow the steps again to reuse the name which I will try.

Answer (score 9):

You must delete **alembic_version** table in your database.

Connect to your database, and execute:

```
DROP TABLE alembic_version;
```

Please check the following answer for more details about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32356600

Answer (score 2):

Go to `versions/` inside `migrations/`.

If you do not see the folder `versions/` or there is not a revision inside the folder `versions/`, type the following command to create a revision:

```
flask db revision
```

You'll get a revision inside the `versions/` folder. Open it and replace the revision id with '470572fac7a1':

```
revision = "470572fac7a1"
```

Type `flask db migrate` again.

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

pull last version from github.
And then backup your prod db. Then restore your local db.
Delete your alembic table (with cascade).

Open your terminal (with venv)
write code below:

```
rm - rf migrations
python manage.py db init
```

and open migrations folder. Right click on alembic.ini and choose git>rollback>ok.

```
python manage.py db migrate
python manage.py db upgrade
```

or

```
python manage.py db stamp head
python manage.py db migrate
python manage.py db upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `alembic downgrade base` to reset to initial revision if you have the file for base version.

If you don't have any revision file (even base revision) you can delete the `alembic_version` table from postgres with `drop table <schema>.alembic_version` and run `alembic ensure_version` to recreate the version table and then setup base revision file.